# i would like to assign subclasses to the charecter? how do i do this?

Tags: python, class, subclass

the problem i has is that the errors that occur are found in the code that works. it doesnt make sence.

my code is:

```
import random
import pickle


class person():
  def __init__(self, name, hp, luck, xp, level, gold, age, location, strength, intellegence):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp
    self.luck = luck
    self.xp = xp
    self.level = level
    self.strength = strength
    self.gold = gold
    self.location = location
    self.age = age
    self.intellegence = intellegence
    #self.x = 0
    #self.y = 0
    
  def talk(self):
    return "hello my name is %s. i have %d strength. i am %d years old. i am from %s. I have %d intellence" %(self.name,self.strength,self.age,self.location, self.intellegence)
  
#def walk(self,newlocation):
#  self.x += movex
#  self.y += movey
#  self.location = newlocation
  
  def takedmg(self, amount):
    self.hp = self.hp - amount
  
  def heal(self, amount):
    self.hp = self.hp + amount
    
  def attack(self):
    pass 

  
  
  
allpeople = []  

def createperson():
  global allpeople
  name = input("enter name: ")
  hp = 100
  luck = random.randint(1,15)
  xp = 0
  level = 1
  gold = 0
  age = int(input("enter age: "))
  location = input("enter location: ")
  strength = random.randint(1,25)
  intellegence = 50
  aperson = person(name, hp, luck, xp, level, gold, age, location, strength, intellegence)
  allpeople.append(aperson)
  savedata()
  

def findchara():
  charaname = input("enter the name of the charecter: ")
  for foundchara in allpeople:
    if foundchara.name == charaname:
      print("found \n")
      return(foundchara)
    return""
  
  
def savedata():
  savedata = open("mypeople.pickle","wb")
  pickle.dump(allpeople,savedata)
  savedata.close()

def loaddata():
  global allpeople
  loaddata = open("mypeople.pickle","rb")
  allpeople = pickle.load(loaddata)
  loaddata.close()

class warrior(person):
  def __init__(self, name, hp, luck, xp, level, gold, age, location, strength, intellegence):
    person.__init__(self)
    class1 = warrior
  
class mage(person):
  def __init__(self, name, hp, luck, xp, level, gold, age, location, strength, intellegence):
    person.__init__(self)
    class1 = mage
  
class trader(person):
  def __init__(self, name, hp, luck, xp, level, gold, age, location, strength, intellegence):
    person.__init__(self)
    class1 = trader

def talk_warrior(person, warrior):
  self.strength = self.strength + 15
  self.intellegence = self.intellegence - self.intellegence + random.randint(0,5)
  return "Hi, name is %s. %d strength. I am %d. from %s. intellegence? %d" %(self.name,self.strength,self.age,self.location,self.intellegence)
  
def talk_mage(person, mage):
  self.strength = self.strength - self.strength + random.randint(0,5)
  self.intellegence = self.intellegence + 50
  return "Hello my name is The Great MAGE %s. I have %d strength DONT QUESTION MY STRENGTH. I am %d years old. I happened to be from %s. my intellegence also happens to be %d which is superior to everyone else." %(self.name,self.strength,self.age,self.location,self.intellegence)
  
def talk_trader(person, trader):
  return "Hello my name is %s. I have %d strength. I am %d years old. I am from %s. I am very average and my intellegence is %d " %(self.name,self.strength,self.age,self.location,self.intellegence)
  

loaddata()  

def classmenu():
  charaloop = True   
  while charaloop == True:
    option = int(input("1. warrior \n2. mage \n3. trader \n9. change class \n0. exit \n"))
    if option == 1:
      classchara = findchara()
      class1 = warrior
      print("Class has been set to warrior.")
      talk_warrior()
    elif option == 2:
      classchara = findchara()
      class1 = mage
      print("Class has been set set to mage.")
      talk_mage()
    elif option == 3:
      classchara = findchara()
      class1 = trader
      print("Class has been set to trader.")
      talk_trader()
    elif option == 9:
      pass
    elif option == 0:
      print("returning to main menu. :) \n")
      charaloop = False
      savedata()
    else:
      print("invalid choice")
  
def menu():
  mainloop = True   
  while mainloop == True:
    option = int(input("1. create character. \n2. character list. \n3. look for a charecter. \n4. select charecter class. \n8. continue... \n9. delete character from list. \n0. exit \n choice: "))
    if option == 1:
      print("you will now create your character!!!")
      createperson()
    elif option == 2:
      for aPerson in allpeople:
        print(aPerson.talk())
    elif option == 3:
      findchara()
    elif option == 4:
      classmenu()
    elif option == 8:
      if class1 == warrior:
        talk_warrior()
      elif class1 == mage:
        talk_mage()
      elif class1 == trader:
        talk_trader()
      else:
        print("ERROR!")
    elif option == 9:
      chara = findchara()
      allpeople.remove(chara)
      print("charecter removed")
      savedata()
    elif option == 0:
      print("bye!!! :)")
      mainloop = False
      savedata()
    else:
      print("invalid choice")
  
menu()
```

the errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python stuff\python chara game ulsfdgklfsgnklfs.py", line 173, in <module>
    menu()
  File "D:\python stuff\python chara game ulsfdgklfsgnklfs.py", line 151, in menu
    classmenu()
  File "D:\python stuff\python chara game ulsfdgklfsgnklfs.py", line 118, in classmenu
    talk_warrior()
TypeError: talk_warrior() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'person' and 'warrior'
```

the code is meant to run in the shell and is a simple class and subclass game that the player creates a character and then assigns it a subclass which changes the attributes of the character. this is where my problems started. in the future I want the character to be able to travel and then will encounter monsters attack and receive damage.

id like to hear some advice on what I could do to improve and make the code better smoother and also fix these problems that have occurred. I've only been coding for a while so there is allot of things wrong with this code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error message is clear. You defined `talk_warrior()` to take two inputs (`person` and `warrior`) but then are calling `talk_warrior()` with no inputs at all. `talk_mage` and `talk_trader` have similar problems. Either redefine those function so that they don't take inputs, or provide inputs when calling them.